# Reading String from the File

Tags: java

What am I doing wrong in the code by reading String. 
Suppose the following `String` is passed as a `layout`:

```
String m = "..z\n"+
          "...\n"+
          "...\n"+
          "...\n"+
          "z..\n"+
          "";
```

My method should return the same result but it's not returning me anything, it does not pring anything. Please do not suggest using `StringBuilder` or smth similar. Can smb please help me out with this?

```
public static Shape makeShape(String layout,char displayChar)
  {
      Shape result;
      int height = 0;
      int width = 0;
      Scanner data = new Scanner(layout);
      char[][] temp;
      while(data.hasNextLine())
      {
          String line = data.nextLine();
          height = line.length();
          width++;
      }
      temp = new char[height][width];

      Scanner data2 = new Scanner(layout);
      while(data.hasNextLine())
      {
          String line2 = data.nextLine();
          if(line2.charAt(0) == '.' && line2.charAt(width) == '.')
              throw new FitItException("Empty borders!");

            else {

                for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
                    for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
                        //System.out.println(line2.charAt(c));

                        if (temp[r][c] == '.') {
                            temp[r][c] = displayChar;
                        }
                        System.out.println(line2.charAt(temp[r][c]));

                    }
            }
      }
      result = new CreateShape(height, width, displayChar);
      return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look **carefully** at these two lines:

```
  Scanner data2 = new Scanner(layout);
  while(data.hasNextLine())
```

Do you see something wrong with ... the ... variable ... names ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the code and string above width would be 5 or 6. No line is more than 3 so   `line2.charAt(width)` would throw an exception?